# sh: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied

Tags: linux, ssh

please help me

[Permission denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRNhT.png)

Linux ns1 2.6.32-042stab123.3 #1 SMP Fri May 5 12:29:05 MSK 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
[root@ns1 /]# whoami
root
[root@ns1 /]# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           8.0G        720M        124M        128M        7.2G        7.2G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
[root@ns1 /]# ls -l /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 26 21:16 /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
[root@ns1 /]# sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
bash: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied
[root@ns1 /]# sudo sh -c 'echo 1 >  /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches' 
sh: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied
[root@ns1 /]# sudo sh -c "/usr/bin/echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
sh: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied
[root@ns1 /]# echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
tee: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied
1
[root@ns1 /]# sudo sync; echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches >/dev/null
tee: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied
[root@ns1 /]# free -m && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           8192         696         146         128        7348        7376
Swap:             0           0           0
bash: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied
```

Comment: Is it a virtual machine you are trying this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It is working

```
echo 3 | sudo -i tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```